# IOS - Build project with external libraries

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, compilation, libraries

What I'm looking for it's something that maybe isn't possible, but perhaps someone can find an alternative.

I'm trying to make a program, that with a master-detail, show 'components'.

Each component could be a simply button, a table view, a music player or whatever. Not strings or any type of data, but functionalities.

So each component could need an specific library or framework, and its own xib.

The problem is that these components are dynamic, other people are going to be adding more on the future, and I wouldn't be modifying the project at every change.

Is there a manner to download code (.h or .m or .xib or entire libs) and execute them on the project?
Or other way to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats simply not possible. You are only allowed to link against static libraries (obviously at compile time), with the only exception being the shipped libraries and frameworks that come with the iOS SDK (eg. UIKit.framework, libz.dylib). The AppStore guidelines forbid you to download and execute code on a users device, so your App idea is simply not possible.